# Pagination script - Date/time in TV guide shows as 15-01-2010 10:01:00

Tags: php, apache, pagination

This is from my TV guide pagination script (note, the top half is not mentioned as there are no problems with the code in the beginning):

```
   class paginationData {
```

private $program;
 private $channel;
        private $airdate;
 private $expiration;
 private $episode;
 private $setReminder;

public function __construct($program, $channel, $airdate, $expiration, $episode, $setReminder)
 {
  $this->program = $program;
  $this->channel = $channel;
  $this->airdate =   $airdate;
  $this->expiration = $expiration;
  $this->episode = $episode;
  $this->setReminder = $setReminder;
  $now         = time();
 }

//This function shows the data
 public function display()
 {
        if((int)date('Ymd') === (int)date('Y-m-d', $airdate)) $dateFormat = 'g:ia';
        elseif((int)date('Y') === (int)date('Y', $airdate)) $dateFormat = 'F jS - g:ia';
        else $dateFormat = 'F jS, Y - g:ia';

```
         $airdateFormatted = date($dateFormat, $airdate, $now);
```

echo ''."\n".
    ' **'.$this->program.'**'."\n".
    ' showing on '.$this->channel.''."\n".
       ' '.date($this->airdate).''."\n".
    ' '.$this->episode.''."\n".
    ' '.$this->setReminder.''."\n".
    ''."\n";
 }
     }

The airdates always render as the following:

```
      2010-01-26 00:25:00
```

but I am not sure how to get strtotime used effectively in this.

In an earlier version of the site, before I used pagination, this worked

```
      if(date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', $airdate)) {
    // Same date, show only time
    $dateFormat = 'g:ia';
} elseif(date('Y') == date('Y', $airdate)) {
    // Same year, show date without year
    $dateFormat = 'F jS - g:ia';
} else {
    // Other cases, show full date
    $dateFormat = 'F jS, Y - g:ia';
}

$airdateFormatted = date($dateFormat, $airdate);

echo "<tr><td><b>$programme</b></td><td>showing on $channel</td>";
echo "<td>$airdateFormatted</td><td>$episode</td><td>$setreminder</td></tr>";
```

but I'm not sure how to get $airdateFormatted to work properly in this script, which is a modified version of someone else's script, that I have customised to my needs.

Any help on ensuring that I can get datetime to render as the following:

```
 January 27th - 9:25am
```

and not

```
     2010-01-27 00:25:00
```

The site's working, it's just the fine detail with regard to thid that I'm struggling with - I have tried for myself, but always end up with undefined errors, so revert back to the default config.

Any help you have would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use

[strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

on the time they give you, and put that value in your date() call